# How are Apache Rewrite Rules Interpreted in Combination?

Tags: apache, configuration, url-rewriting, virtualhost

This is all taking place on a LAMP stack within a <VirtualHost *:80> context.  I'm using

```
RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com/
```

to redirect all http requests to https.  I also have old incoming broken "http://..." links which I want to redirect, and this seems like the best place to do them, rather than on the https side, which would involve sending a pointless redirect to a not-found https page.

If I stack Redirects like this:

```
RedirectPermanent /specific/2020/url1.php https://example.com/2021/url1.html
RedirectPermanent /specific/2020/url2.php https://example.com/2021/url2.html
RedirectPermanent /specific/2020/url2.php https://example.com/2021/url3.html

RedirectPermanent / https://example.com/
```

Is there any potential for conflict between the "url#" redirects and the "/" redirect?

I can't find anything in Apache's documentation to explain how these rules would be interpreted in combination.  Does a pattern match for "url1" terminate the script in the way, for example, that the "L" flag does with RewriteRule ?

Or is there the possibility that the "/" -> https line gets applied because it matches also?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

The doc says:

> First, all Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed, and therefore a request that matches a `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` will never have Aliases applied. Second, the Aliases and Redirects are processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with the first match taking precedence.

I'd prefer more explicit wording, but I interpret this as saying when a match occurs, the subsequent Redirects are ignored.